# Only Show Excerpt After First 3 Posts

Tags: loop, excerpt, exclude

I'm using the template part below and would like to only show the excerpt after the first 3 posts. The first 3 posts are formatted differently as "header" posts and thus I'd rather not have an excerpt for those posts.

Could someone help me with the PHP?

```
<div class="content-block-archive">

     <div class="content-block-archive-thumbnail">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?></a>
     </div>

     <div class="content-block-archive-meta">
<h2 class="content-block-archive-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

          <div class="content-block-archive-author"> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> | <?php echo get_the_date(); ?> 
          </div>

          <div class="content-block-archive-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a count variable and count how many times the page has looped and only show the excerpt if the count is 3 or greater.:

```
<?php

    $Count = 0;
?>
<div class="content-block-archive">

     <div class="content-block-archive-thumbnail">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?></a>
     </div>

     <div class="content-block-archive-meta">
<h2 class="content-block-archive-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

          <div class="content-block-archive-author"> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> | <?php echo get_the_date(); ?> 
          </div>
        <?php 
        if ($Count >= 3) { ?>
            <div class="content-block-archive-excerpt">
                <?php 
                    the_excerpt(); 
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php 
        } 
        $Count ++;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lewis, I don't have a flag. I just identify the first three posts with CSS child selectors to format and then have CSS for the rest of the articles.

Comment: I've updated the answer to user a count instead of a flag, let me know if that works.

Comment: That broke something. No errors in the inspector tool. It loads the header fine then give a Wordpress error "The site is experiencing technical difficulties."

Comment: I've updated again, i missed a closing php tag sorry.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks Lewis!

Comment: Glad I could help